# How to decode and play the .h264 video from amazon s3 server in android?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, server

I have .h264 videos in server, how to decode that video and playing in android?

I am using the FFMPEG to play those videos but in FFMPEG sample it takes 
the video from SD-card and successfully play's the video. I am using the 
surface view to play those videos. My question is how to play .h264 video from amazon s3 server in android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post url for video...

Comment: you can also put%20 at the place of " " space it cold decode url then you can play his video.....

Comment: There is no need to decode video just decode url only if you will decode url of video you will see wrong decoding by android Example for  http//:www.google.com   decoding is  http%3S%2F%3S//www.google.com etc like this

Comment: @amitsharma Thank for reply yes it is not decode the question is how to access (stream?) files from S3 server? sample url is      https://s3.amazonaws.com/201501bk/filename.h264

Comment: this is not complete url or not any video here Look at here i am posting  answer

Comment: what you want exactly Post here

Answer (score 0):

Make your videos(files) in the s3 bucket public,
and use that public url, it will be accessible everywhere.

**EDIT**

You can use a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html). Here is an example:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
//Use a media controller so that you can scroll the video contents
//and also to pause, start the video.
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this); 
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
videoView.start();
```

You should provide the URI (having a `String url` variable, where it has the url of the video) with this code `Uri.parse(url)`. And also be sure if the url is appropriate. Also provide the appropriate permissions to your app (since it uses the internet you will need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >` in your app's `Manifest.xml` Finally you should define your activity `MediaPlayerActivity` in in your app's `Manifest.xml`

You can also use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). The Android developers site has a good tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

**H.264**

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), Android supports h.264 Baseline Profile playback. So your h.264 video is not Baseline Profile or possibly it contains an unsupported audio.

You should note that there are many h.64 flavors, so you should check your video file: http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2010/07/h264-video.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, ya all my url in public then how to play .h264 video url from server in android using ffmpeg?

Comment: @Ashok You dont have to use ffmpeg for playing the .h264 video as it is just the codec of mp4 video

Comment: @salman thanks,video view is not supporting the .h264 fiels, I am trying your code it shows the can't play video error.

Comment: @Ashok Please check your codec again, as this is working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: And @Ashok what android version are you running at? its only possible for android 3.0+

Comment: @salman it is raw .h264 format file and can you provide any sample for this?

Answer (score -1):

You need make sure your H.264 video is in the codec that your Android device can accept, otherwise, you need re-encode it.

Comment: H.264 is a codec, and ffmpeg can decode movies in H.264, so this is not the case for re-encoding. The question was about how to access (stream?) files from S3 server.

Comment: @user2622016 yes you are right,the question is how to access (stream?) files from S3 server?is there any sample for this please provide me thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know. I really don't know anything about S3. I assume some API could be available for Andrid like the one for PHP http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html

Answer (score -1):

I have Complete solve my issue by this code May be It will Help you.

```
 layout.xml

    <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
```

.class

```
         String FileUrl="decoded url";
         MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(FileUrl);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
```

manifesto.xml

permitions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: thanks for reply this code is not worked for me it shows the error like can't play this video and give me your mail id i am sending my sample to you

Comment: Thanks for test,you are doing testing in my Url or any other?

Comment: this is your case no problem i have time today to do these things today

Comment: Above code is working in mp4 videos but .h264 videos are not played in above code. and Thanks for your support

Comment: ask this to @Ashok he has done with amazon server this format of code executed when your video on your server i have try with my server not amazon server...